# Ignite persisting a Set: Cannot find metadata for object with compact footer

Tags: java, ignite

I am trying to create a Ignite Cache with persistence for Sets of Model. That is, `IgniteCache<String, Set<Model>>`.

While running it locally, everything works. I can restart the application and Ignite loads its persisted database.

But when running with Docker or Kubernetes (with mounted volume for persistence) I cannot restart the application. Otherwise I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Cannot find metadata for object with compact footer: 2097659979
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1337)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.cacheException(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1758)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.get(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:931)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.get(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:640)
    at com.jesjobom.IgnitePersistence.remove(IgnitePersistence.java:81)
    at com.jesjobom.IgnitePersistence.add(IgnitePersistence.java:66)
    at com.jesjobom.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Cannot find metadata for object with compact footer: 2097659979
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7429)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:172)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get0(GridCacheAdapter.java:4723)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:4697)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:1415)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.get(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:928)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Cannot find metadata for object with compact footer: 2097659979
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.getOrCreateSchema(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:2012)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.<init>(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.<init>(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.reader(BinaryObjectImpl.java:832)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:795)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:177)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapKnownCollection(CacheObjectUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:181)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:125)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1773)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1761)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.setResult(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:695)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.localGet(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:477)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.mapKeyToNode(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:354)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.map(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:225)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.init(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:217)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedCache.getAsync(GridDhtColocatedCache.java:272)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get0(GridCacheAdapter.java:4716)
    ... 7 more
^C
```

I created a GitHub repo to make it easy to test... https://github.com/jesjobom/ignite-persistence-test/

Main configuration:

```java
System.setProperty(IgniteSystemProperties.IGNITE_NO_SHUTDOWN_HOOK, "true");

IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();

//Region for persistent (in disk) data
DataRegionConfiguration persistence = new DataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        .setInitialSize(64 * 1024 * 1024)
        .setMaxSize(128 * 1024 * 1024).setName(PERSISTENT_REGION_NAME);

DataStorageConfiguration dataStorageConfiguration = new DataStorageConfiguration().setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(persistence);

//Persistence location config
dataStorageConfiguration.setWalPath(STORAGE_LOCATION + "/wal")
        .setWalArchivePath(STORAGE_LOCATION + "/wal-arc")
        .setStoragePath(STORAGE_LOCATION + "/store");

igniteConfiguration.setDataStorageConfiguration(dataStorageConfiguration);

ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfiguration);
ignite.cluster().active(true);

store = ignite.getOrCreateCache(new CacheConfiguration<String, Set<Model>>()
        .setDataRegionName(PERSISTENT_REGION_NAME)
        .setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED)
        .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
        .setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC)
        .setName("store")
        .setIndexedTypes(String.class, Set.class)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like IGNITE_HOME directory refers to a volume/folder that is cleared on restarts. Please set that variable to a path that is not changed over restarts the way you did for the storage and WAL.

Comment: Thank you. That was it... I thought it wasn't the answer since the Javadoc for IGNITE_HOME says "Defines Ignite installation folder". But it is also used to define the Work directory. So, defining IGNITE_HOME or using `igniteConfiguration.setWorkDirectory("persistent/path")` works. Strangely I don't need any of these solutions when my "value" is not a `Set<Value>`, but a single `Value`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I updated `IGNITE_HOME` variable with persistent path and problem with compact footers was resolved. Moreover when my pod was redeployed all data was cleared despite the specified persistent storage path. This fix also solved this problem. Thanks again! It was not obvious at all.