Upgrading to Ignite 2.16 with persistence enabled gives error
I am trying to upgrade Apache Ignite to 2.16 with Persistence enabled as true. I am getting the below error:

org.apache.ignite.client.ClientException: Ignite failed to process request [31]: 50000: Failed to execute map query on remote node [nodeId=c670b5a3-03f4-4261-a8a2-7085b20cb089, errMsg=General error: "class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Cannot find metadata for object with compact footer (Ignite work directory might have been cleared after restart. Make sure that IGNITE_HOME does not point to a temp folder or any other folder that is destroyed/cleared on restarts) [typeId=396738638, IGNITE_HOME='/opt/ignite/apache-ignite']"; SQL statement:SELECTM__Z0.MEASUREMENTSTATUS __C0_0,COUNT() __C0_1FROM PUBLIC.MEASUREMENT M__Z0WHERE M__Z0.LASTUPDATED >= TIMESTAMPADD('SECOND', -300, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())GROUP BY M__Z0.MEASUREMENTSTATUS [50000-197]] (server status code [1]) at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.convertException(TcpClientChannel.java:475) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]   at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.receive(TcpClientChannel.java:421) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.service(TcpClientChannel.java:311) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.lambda$service$0(ReliableChannel.java:205) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0] at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.applyOnDefaultChannel(ReliableChannel.java:835) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.applyOnDefaultChannel(ReliableChannel.java:788) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.service(ReliableChannel.java:205) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]  at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.service(ReliableChannel.java:186) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]  at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.GenericQueryPager.next(GenericQueryPager.java:93) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]  at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientQueryCursor$1.nextPage(ClientQueryCursor.java:93) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientQueryCursor$1.hasNext(ClientQueryCursor.java:76) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0] at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]    at org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.query.IgniteRepositoryQuery$QueryCursorWrapper.getAll(IgniteRepositoryQuery.java:963) ~[ignite-spring-data-ext-2.0.0.jar!/:2.0.0]    at org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.query.IgniteRepositoryQuery.transformQueryCursor(IgniteRepositoryQuery.java:580) ~[ignite-spring-data-ext-2.0.0.jar!/:2.0.0] at org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.query.IgniteRepositoryQuery.execute(IgniteRepositoryQuery.java:360) ~[ignite-spring-data-ext-2.0.0.jar!/:2.0.0]  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5]   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5]   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]   at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy132.getMeasurementStatusAndCount(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]   at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy132.getMeasurementStatusAndCount(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:72) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMapMany.java:49) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9]  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9]    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FluxSubscribeOn.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9] at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9] at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientServerError: Ignite failed to process request [31]: 50000: Failed to execute map query on remote node [nodeId=c670b5a3-03f4-4261-a8a2-7085b20cb089, errMsg=General error: "class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Cannot find metadata for object with compact footer (Ignite work directory might have been cleared after restart. Make sure that IGNITE_HOME does not point to a temp folder or any other folder that is destroyed/cleared on restarts) [typeId=396738638, IGNITE_HOME='/opt/ignite/apache-ignite']"; SQL statement:SELECTM__Z0.MEASUREMENTSTATUS __C0_0,COUNT() __C0_1FROM PUBLIC.MEASUREMENT M__Z0WHERE M__Z0.LASTUPDATED >= TIMESTAMPADD('SECOND', -300, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())GROUP BY M__Z0.MEASUREMENTSTATUS [50000-197]] (server status code [1])

It works with Persistence enabled as false and true for Ignite versions< 2.16.
Please suggest any fixes for this.

Have you tried the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529702/ignite-persisting-a-set-cannot-find-metadata-for-object-with-compact-footer ?

I tried adding IGNITE_HOME as an env variable and giving a value as "/opt/ignite/apache-ignite" but still get the error as "run.sh is not present in that path". However, I can see it's present in the above path, not sure what is wrong.

Have you check that your persistence directory is clear? Is it a valid directory? Does it have sufficient space? Have you considered using 3 drives? (One for WAL, one for archive and one for data)? After persistence is enabled did you create a new cache to work with? So many questions, ...

Actually, for Ignite 2.15 it's a working setup. We have volumes of type Host Path created for WAL and Persistence and that works till Ignite 2.15 without any error. But, on upgrading Ignite to 2.16, I start getting the above error. I tried adding another volume for this IGNITE_HOME for /opt/ignite/apache-ignite but still get error as it's unable to find run.sh. To me it's looking like path of IGNITE_HOME is incorrect but not sure what it should be.
